# Segment crossing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory

I need an ideea of an algorithm to solve a puzzle 'game'.
The game is :

- is given N number of line segments by coordinates
  [(X1n,Y1n),(X2n,Y2n)]
- some of segments have the same ends

We've got something like :

[image: unsolved puzzle]

To solve the puzzle we need to move ends of segments in such a way that none of segments intersect (cross), except for ends.
The above example solved, looks like :

[image]

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this type of puzzle ?

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is not planar, than there is no solution. If the graph IS planar, there are many solutions, but they are somewhat complicated. See [this Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing)